Oracle Scheduler Job Fails to Run: Not an Appropriate Date Error
I am trying to create a scheduler job in Oracle. The job gets created and appears in the list of jobs, but it fails to run at the scheduled time, instead giving an error. For example, right now it gives the error '04-JUL-24' is not an appropriate date. How can I fix this issue?
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RPPR_DAILY_REP_CALL AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(JOB_NAME        => 'DAILY_BATCH',
                            JOB_TYPE        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                            JOB_ACTION      => 'BEGIN RPPR_DAILY_REP_BATCH;END;',
                            START_DATE      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                            REPEAT_INTERVAL => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=8; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0',
                            ENABLED         => TRUE,
                            AUTO_DROP       => FALSE,
                            COMMENTS        => 'JOB TO RUN PROCEDURE AT 8AM');

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(JOB_NAME => 'DAILY_BATCH');
END;

Error faced:
ORA-23319: parameter value "04-JUL-24" is not appropriate
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 84
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 163
ORA-06512: at "REGREP.RPPR_DAILY_REP_BATCH", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 209
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 594
ORA-06512: at "REGREP.RPPR_DAILY_REP_CALL", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 3

While I run
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB('DAILY_BATCH');--ONLY WHEN JOB ALREADY EXISTS
RPPR_DAILY_REP_CALL;
END;


curious question: what is the resulf of this qurey
select sysdate from dual,
replace systimestamp START_DATE   with sysdate or sysdate+1

well sysdate return proper date of format 'M/d/yyyy H12:mm:ss'
systimestamp returns the format 'dd-mmm-yy hh12.mm.ss timezone'
I actually changed from systimestamp to sysdate as well, but that didnt help either

I have tried changing the NLS_DATE_FORMAT to see if it resolves the "inappropriate date" error, but the error persists. Additionally, the parameter changes to whatever format I set, but it doesn't seem to affect the issue.

Date "formatting" is only applied to the display of the date in a query response, or to set the default to_date conversion when providing a string value. It doesn't do anything to the underlying date or timestamp datatype used by dbms_scheduler, or stored in a date or timestamp column, or any other query.

Next question: is the error being thrown by dbms_scheduler, or by your RPPR_DAILY_REP_BATCH procedure? Could you edit your question to include the entire error message text (not a screenshot)?

I discovered the issue: the procedure RPPR_DAILY_REP_BATCH was submitting jobs using SYSDATE when triggered. The problem arose because SYSDATE was being concatenated improperly in the WHAT section of DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT inside the body of RPPR_DAILY_REP_BATCH. The correct approach is to ensure SYSDATE is treated as a string for concatenation.
Initially, I used:
dbms_job.submit(
    job => v_job,
    what => 'begin prc_submit_job(' || sysdate || '); end;'
);

This caused an error due to the direct inclusion of SYSDATE. To fix this, I converted SYSDATE to a string using TO_CHAR and wrapped it with TO_DATE in the WHAT section. The corrected code is:
dbms_job.submit(
    job => v_job,
    what => 'begin prc_submit_job(to_date(''' || to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ''', ''DD-MON-YYYY'')); end;'
);

This ensures that SYSDATE is properly formatted and concatenated as a string, avoiding the previous error.

Are you sure that problem is related to dbms_scheduler? I have created your procedure and job in my own environment with only job_action value changed and faced no errors while running it.
Here is the procedure :

And this one is result of running the procedure with :
BEGIN 
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB('DAILY_BATCH');--ONLY WHEN JOB ALREADY EXISTS
 RPPR_DAILY_REP_CALL;
END;


And this is how the job is listed in user_scheduler_jobs:

My guess is to examine RPPR_DAILY_REP_BATCH procedure, probably something is happening there.

Well, i think there must be some privileges issue with scheduler. I can see the job created by scheduler but it always is failed due to date inappropriate. what the rep_batch do is submit jobs of different procedures which run fine when i trigger the rep batch manually without scheduler. so it must not be an issue with that. I am actually facing error in scheduling of jobs or scheduler. that is my cincern, even the scheduler runs fine when there is no interval of repeating the job.

Thank you for your help and guidance. Through trial and error with different approaches to setting the scheduler dates, I eventually isolated the problem to the content within the procedure body. Ultimately, I discovered that date format of SYSDATE was the root cause of the issue which should have been string while submitting as job.

Glad you figured it out! Date formats and their string representations are indeed may cause a problem
